# UIButton / Attributed Text - Varying line Spacing

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nsattributedstring

I've got a component in a Swift 5 project inheriting from UIButton. The button has two sections of text: a heading (1 line) and a subheading (1+ lines). The two sections of text are formatted as a single attributed string which is used as the value for `UIButton.titlelabel`.

I need the line spacing between the title heading and subheading to be a value `a`, and the spacing between each line of the subheading to be a *different* value `b`. I've tried the following, to no avail (the spacing for the entire attributed text is set to the subtitle spacing). Is it possible to have a varying line height, or do I need a different approach?

```
let buttonText = NSMutableAttributedString()

let titleStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
titleStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1
        
let title = NSAttributedString(string: title,
                               attributes: [
                               NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.title3,
                               NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: titleStyle
                               ])
buttonText.append(title)

let subtitleStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
subtitleStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 0.7
            
let subtitle = NSAttributedString(string: subtitle,
                                  attributes: [
                                  NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.body,
                                  NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: subtitleStyle
                                ])
            
buttonText.append(subtitle)
```

Comment: Does that give you "varying line spacing" if you use a label and set `.attributedText`? If not, then it's not going to work in a `UIButton`. If yes, then I'm not sure how we can help you with your *"component ... inheriting from UIButton"* without seeing **that** code.

Comment: Is this what you're going for? https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV2eD.png